# Translate animation from top to middle of the screen

Tags: android, animation

I am working for  Translate animation of two images overlapping each other and both Images should translate from  top  to middle of the screen. plesee share some sample programmes for this

Help is always appreciated, ....Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="50%p" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

in java file..

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.anim);
anim.setInterpolator((new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()));
anim.setFillAfter(true);
ImageView.setAnimation(anim);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but how can we enable and disable the two Images continiueosly one after another. could u share the functionality

Comment: i have no code for it but i can explain u ... u can set visible-invisible for imageview as per your choice ...

Answer (score 3):

To animate from **Top to middle** of screen it should be something like this

**anmation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate
      android:fromYDelta="-50%p"
      android:toYDelta="0%p"
      android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

And to use this animation

```
Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.animation);
    tv_logo.startAnimation(bottomUp);
```